# How to extract lines from a text file which contains ERROR key word in the sentence using VB6

Tags: logging, vb6

How to extract lines from a text file which contains ERROR key word in the sentence using VB6.
I am very new to VB6 and want to extract multiple lines from a log file and put them in the last of log file.

LOG FIlE :Log.txt

2012-10-29 22:39:47 ------------------------------------------

2012-10-29 22:39:47 The application is starting...

2012-10-29 22:39:47 Deleting flag files...

2012-10-29 22:39:47 Authenticated successfully as user "administrator"

2012-10-29 22:40:11 Displaying role selection dialog box...

2012-10-29 22:40:13 Role selected: TESTROLE

2012-10-29 22:40:16 Checking installation status...

2012-10-29 22:41:21 Successfully connected to BO server

2012-10-29 22:41:21 The process completed

2012-10-30 20:19:35 ------------------------------------------

2012-10-30 20:19:35 The application is starting...

2012-10-30 20:19:35 Deleting flag files...

2012-10-29 22:40:11 Error connecting to server

2012-10-29 22:40:16 Checking installation status...

2012-10-29 22:41:21 Error in function ShellAndWait. Error code: 0

2012-10-29 22:41:21 ERROR: 
2012-10-29 22:41:21 ERROR: Method '~' of object '~' failed

2012-10-29 22:41:21 Searching for local source folder...

2012-10-29 22:41:21 ERROR: Method '~' of object '~' failed

2012-10-29 22:41:21 Copying folder \xxx.xxx.x.xx\xyz\Script to E:\

2012-10-29 22:41:21 NON-CRITICAL ERROR:Error copying folder \xxx.xxx.x.xx\admin Method

2012-10-29 22:41:21 The process completed

In the above log file i want to extract lines containing Error keyword in the senetence for current session and want to collect all those line and put them in the last of current logs. For example in above log file current log is started at  this line for this session

"2012-10-30 20:19:35 ------------------------------------------"

and ends with line

"2012-10-29 22:41:21 The process completed  "

so i want to extract line containing Error keyword in between these two lines and put them under this
"2012-10-29 22:41:21 The process completed" line

"2012-10-29 22:41:21 The process completed"

Error Encountered in session 2012-10-29 22:40:11 are listed below

2012-10-29 22:40:11 Error connecting to server

2012-10-29 22:41:21 Error in function ShellAndWait. Error code: 0

2012-10-29 22:41:21 ERROR:

2012-10-29 22:41:21 ERROR: Method '~' of object '~' failed

2012-10-29 22:41:21 ERROR: Method '~' of object '~' failed

012-10-29 22:41:21 NON-CRITICAL ERROR:Error copying folder \xxx.xxx.x.xx\admin Method '~' of object '~'

Is it possible in VB6 ? please guide me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain old native VB6 I/O works fine for something like this.  Even testing against an 80MB test log performance was acceptable.  Bonus: you don't eat vast amounts of RAM doing things this way.

As a bonus, this attempt (a.) I think it does what you asked for, (b.) does a case-insensitive search, and (c.) doesn't get false hits when the sequence "error" occurs within a longer word (e.g. "terror").

It also adds a "*none*" line for sessions that have no "errors" but you could change or delete that as desired and I tweaked your "Error Encountered... are listed below" message to something less clunky.

```
Option Explicit

Private fOrigLog As Integer
Private fNewLog As Integer
Private colErrorLines As Collection
Private strSessionTimestamp As String

Private Sub FlushErrorLines()
    Print #fNewLog, "Errors encountered in session "; _
                    strSessionTimestamp; _
                    " are listed below"
    With colErrorLines
        If .Count = 0 Then
            Print #fNewLog, "*none*"
        Else
            Do While .Count > 0
                Print #fNewLog, .Item(1)
                .Remove 1
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Main()
    Const DASHES As String = "------------------------------------------"
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim strLineUCased As String
    Dim posError As Long

    fOrigLog = FreeFile(0)
    Open "log.txt" For Input As #fOrigLog Len = 32767

    fNewLog = FreeFile(0)
    Open "newlog.txt" For Output As #fNewLog Len = 32767

    Set colErrorLines = New Collection

    Do Until EOF(fOrigLog)
        Line Input #fOrigLog, strLine
        If Mid$(strLine, 21, 42) = DASHES Then
            If Len(strSessionTimestamp) > 0 Then
                FlushErrorLines
            End If
            strSessionTimestamp = Left$(strLine, 19)
            Print #fNewLog, strLine
        Else
            strLineUCased = UCase$(strLine)
            posError = InStr(21, strLineUCased, "ERROR")
            If posError > 0 Then
                'Make sure we have a whole word "ERROR" here:
                If Mid$(strLineUCased, posError - 1, 7) & " " _
                        Like "[!0-9A-Z]ERROR[!0-9A-Z]*" Then
                    colErrorLines.Add strLine
                Else
                    Print #fNewLog, strLine
                End If
            Else
                Print #fNewLog, strLine
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    Close #fOrigLog
    FlushErrorLines
    Close #fNewLog

    MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot buddy......you saved me a lot of time and code works according to my requirement . Cheers :)

Comment: @@Bob77 Hey Bob one more question ...the above code does the same what i asked but it also remove the error log lines in between the logs and place them after the session log for all the session. i just do not want to remove those error logs which came in sequence.

Comment: I thought you wanted to "extract" error lines and put them after the session.  If you just want to put *copies* after the session then just print all of the lines (get rid of the two Elses under detection of "error" and always Print there).

Answer (score 1):

some quick sample code :

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim lngLine As Long
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim intFile As Integer
  Dim strData As String
  Dim strLine() As String
  Dim strErrors As String
  'set filename
  strFile = "c:\temp\test.log"
  intFile = FreeFile
  'openj file
  Open strFile For Input As #intFile
    'read data from file
    strData = Input(LOF(intFile), #intFile)
  Close #intFile
  'split data into an array of lines
  strLine = Split(strData, vbCrLf)
  'empty error list
  strErrors = ""
  'loop through all lines of data
  For lngLine = 0 To UBound(strLine)
    If InStr(strLine(lngLine), "Error") > 0 Then
      'add line to errors if it contains the word "Error"
      strErrors = strErrors & strLine(lngLine) & vbCrLf
    End If
  Next lngLine
  'show the errors
  Print strErrors
End Sub
```

Comment: If you anticipate that the log file is large, or the amount of errors to be large, I would recommend avoiding the string concatenation shown here `strErrors = strErrors & strLine(lngLine) & vbCrLf`.  VB6 string concatenation is **extremely** slow when done many times and with large strings, a scenario which this code may easily come across.  Check out this [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20040502143143/http://www.ftponline.com/archives/premier/mgznarch/vbpj/1999/01jan99/bb0199.pdf) on how to make your own VB6 String Builder class that would be dramatically faster with a large log file.

Comment: true, somehow i thought the file wouldnt be that large, i dont know if that was correct. if the file is large you should better not read it in all at once, with the Input() function, but read it in line by line